# Conditionally format value in React-Final-Form based on data in form?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I am displaying a currency value in a react-final-form. I am using a format function on the field.

```
const formatMoney = (value) => {
  if (!value) return value;
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'USD'
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
};
```

The problem is the currency is another option in the form. I do not see a clean way to access the rest of the values inside a format function.

Answer (score 0):

After asking the question, I figured out this work around, pass the values into the render function of the form and pass down to the format function like this:

```
     <Field
      name="total"
      type="text"
      readOnly
      component={LabeledInput}
      placeholder="10"
      label="Total"
      help="Estimated total including tax"
      format={v => formatMoney(v, values.currency)}
    />
```

Comment: Hi there. I have the same problem. Could you please share a codesandbox example?